# Why does the php function each return 4 values?

Tags: php, each

It appears the first 2 (`[1]` and `['value']`)and last 2 (`[0]` and `['key']`) elements are always the same, so what is the point?

```
<?php
$foo = array("bob", "fred", "jussi", "jouni", "egon", "marliese");
$bar = each($foo);
print_r($bar);
?>

Array
(
    [1] => bob
    [value] => bob
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
```

Comment: Some code? I don't understand what your question is...

Comment: But surely the same information could be provided with 50% fewer characters? Why the duplication of information?

Comment: This is well documented behavior: “[Returns the current key and value pair from the array *array*. This pair is returned in a four-element array, with the keys *0*, *1*, *key*, and *value*. Elements *0* and *key* contain the key name of the array element, and *1* and *value* contain the data.](http://php.net/each)”

Comment: Cheers for all the down votes guys, I thought it was a reasonable question. To someone who is not familiar with the specifics of the list function, returning the surplus [0] and [1] keys is not intuitive at all.

Comment: Upvote. Reasonable Question seeing as a `key => value` pair is a pair and not two pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only numeric indicies can be used with [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). That way one can use constructs like:

```
list($key, $val) = each($array);
```

and something like:

```
$item = each($array);
echo $item['key']; // key is easier to understand here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if each returns an array with the keys [value] and [key], surely that makes it an associative array and not a numerically indexed array?

Comment: @Lars list searches for the indicies `0` and `1`. I said numeric indicies, not numeric array. `php > list($a, $b) = array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd');
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in php shell code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in php shell code on line 1
`